# Strcmp crashes application

Tags: c, strcmp

I have this function

```
int does_exist_in_array(char team[], struct team *teams) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_TEAMS_AMOUNT; i++) {
        if(!strcmp(team, teams[i].name)) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It crashes when i run the application. Anyone know what is wrong? Do i use it wrong?

Comment: Look at your arguments with a debugger and make sure they are what you expected.

Comment: this is a bad coding practice - MAX_TEAMS_AMOUNT is a hidden argument which should be explicit, so the caller is responsible for determining the number of teams to be compared.

Comment: @Linuxios `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can happen for a number of reasons:

- Either argument is NULL or otherwise an invalid pointer
- The string pointed by either argument is not 0-terminated
- There are fewer than `MAX_TEAMS_AMOUNT` `team` elements

Comment: `struct team teams[MAX_TEAMS_AMOUNT];` But none of the names have been initialized in the team struct. Don't know if that has something to say? I guess they are just empty as default?

Comment: No you'll need to initialise the name strings. Easiest way for you looks to be adding `= {0}` which will zero-initialise all teams. (I'm assuming name is a char array not a char*)

Comment: @Frank it is char *name in the struct

Comment: `= {0}` will make them NULL, which you could use to mean an empty team, but you'd need to check for that before your strcmp.